# Is it possible to wrap an element to a new row using flexbox or grids?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a customer who wants to wrap the 2nd box in a flexbox display around the bottom of the first to save space.

Here is what the display currently looks like:
[image: Here is what the display currently looks like]

And here is what they want it to look like:
[image: And here is what they want it to look like]

Here is an approximation of our CSS:

```css
.container {
    border: 6px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;
    padding: 20px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-1, .box-2 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Is this request even possible?

EDIT: [Here is an image of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb8Bt.png)

The image is in one box and the title, description, and button are in another box. The client wants the description to start at the top left and go under the image once it gets lower.

Comment: Flex and Grid are designed for square / rectangular areas. Your desired layout would require lots of CSS and/or JavaScript. More knowledge of the overall layout may help provide an alternative solution.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thanks for your help. I edited the post to include an image of what I'm talking about. I'm thinking I'll just need to tell the client it isn't realistic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make Block 1 floated to the left of Block 2.

You can tweak the padding and margins as needed.

```css
.block0 { border: solid 5px darkpurple; }
.block1 { border: solid 5px green; }
.block2 { border: solid 5px purple; }

.block1 { float: left; display: block; width: 50%; }
```

```html
<div class="block0">
  <div class="block1">1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 </div>
  <div class="block2">2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 </div>
</div>
```